# UITextField at the bottom of screen is unseen

Tags: objective-c, uitextfield, visibility

Using `UITextField` that is in the bottom of screen, when the keyboard is opened, user cant see what is he writes because the keyboard covers the textfield.

Is there any way to see what you write or push up the text field page ?

```
userName = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(133, 280, 200, 30)];  
    [userName setDelegate:self];
    [userName setText:@"NickName"];
    [userName setBorderStyle:UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect];
    [userName setTextColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1.0]];
    [[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] view] window] addSubview:userName];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ..YOu have to use that textfield with Scrollview. This way the user can scroll up and so can see what he is typing.

Update: I found [THIS](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/user-interface/adjust-textfield-hidden-by-keyboard.html) link, which satisfy your need.

Comment: You can also make your view (that contains UITextField) go up when user starts to use text field.